# Html.DisplayFor query through other table returning an empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, code-first

I have hit a roadblock when attempting to figure out how to make user profiles using ASP.Net Identity. I have my database set up like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YYcK.png), where `Id` in `AspNetUsers` a foreign key to the table `UserPages`.

I'm using standard code to deliver the model to the view:

```
public ActionResult View(string id)
{
    UserPage userPage = db.UserPages.Find(id);
    (...)
    return View(userPage);
}
```

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;

namespace Citrus.Models
{
    public class UserPage
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public string AboutMe { get; set; }

        public string AvailableTime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And then in the view I can use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AboutMe)
```

to display the property `AboutMe` in the db `UserPages`. But when I try to fetch data from `AspNetUsers` through the model like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Name)
```

I only get an empty string back. `User.Name` is non-nullable, and the entry exists in the database. What is the reason for the method to come back empty, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: What is the controller method and query your using to generate the view where you use `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Name)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Elaborate? I posted the ActionResult in the original post.

Comment: But that is getting values from your `UserPages` table, not the `AspNetUsers` table. What is the model your using in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using `Citrus.Models.UserPage`

Comment: And are you expecting us to guess what that model is? Show it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke My bad, I thought it was pretty obvious based on the db picture. Updated OP with new information.

Comment: Are any of the properties of User loaded? (you possibly need `.Include(x => User)` in your query

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope, I didn't know that you had to do that! An example of how to load such properties would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your EF configuration, but try `UserPage userPage = db.UserPages.Include(x => x.User).Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, that did it for me! Thank you a million! You can submit an answer if you want.

Comment: Need some sleep. Feel free to add your own answer to close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I never included `AspNetUsers` to the `UserPages` query.

```
UserPage userPage = db.UserPages.Find(id);
```

Replacing my query with the following code resolves the problem:

```
UserPage userPage = db.UserPages.Include(x => x.User).Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()
```

I can now get any property of the user by using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Property)`